# Can i convert from byte[] to String in Lambda?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Ok, "ToString()" cannot be translated into a store expression, and error is clear.

This is my code:

```
 var narudzbe = db.Narudzbe
                  .Where(x => x.KupacID == id && x.Status == true)
                  .Select(x => new NarudzbeVM()
                  {
                      BrojNarudzbe = x.BrojNarudzbe,
                      Datum = x.Datum,
                      KupacID = x.KupacID,
                      NarudzbaID = x.NarudzbaID,
                      Otkazano = x.Otkazano,
                      Status = x.Status,
                      StavkeNarudzbe = db.NarudzbaStavke
                                         .Where(y => y.NarudzbaID == x.NarudzbaID)
                                         .Select(z => new NarudzbaStavkeVM()
                                         {
                                             Kolicina = z.Kolicina,
                                             NarudzbaID = z.NarudzbaID,
                                             NarudzbaStavkaID = z.NarudzbaStavkaID,
                                             Proizvod = db.Proizvodi
                                                          .Select(t => new ProizvodTest()
                                                          {
                                                              Cijena = t.Cijena,
                                                              ProizvodID = t.ProizvodID,
                                                              JedinicaMjere = t.JediniceMjere.Naziv,
                                                              Naziv = t.Naziv, 
                                                              Sifra = t.Sifra, 
                                                              SlikaThumb = Convert.ToString(t.SlikaThumb)
                                                           })
                                                          .Where(k => k.ProizvodID == z.ProizvodID)
                                                          .FirstOrDefault()
                                         }).ToList()    
                   }).ToList();
```

I want to convert byte[] to string, since my class accept string for attribut "SlikaThumb". So,

> SlikaThumb = Convert.ToString(t.SlikaThumb)

t.SlikaThumb is type of byte[]. Is there way to do it in lambda ?

Comment: What do you expect the string that you will get as the result will look like?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question. It is byte[] that represent photo from database.

Comment: `String` can only represent text!

Comment: Wait... If that byte array represents an Image on database, why are you trying to convert it to a string?

Comment: I know it. I will explain it better now, i have class "Product", that have attribute with name "Photo" type of byte[]. I have to send data from WebAPI to android, and have to convert byte[] to string, so i create new class that i will use to send data to Android, that contain string instead of byte[].

Comment: So you need to convert your byte array to an Base64 encoded string, then?

Comment: I can say: Product p = db.Products.Find(id); and than, 

ProductVM v = new ProductVM()
{
  photo = Convert.ToBase64String(p.photo)
};

But i want to do it in lamba.

Comment: Make your VM class just accept the byte[], you can expose a 2nd property that turns it in to a string behind the scences.

Comment: Than i have to send byte[] to android, i create VM to avoid that. Is there other solution ?

Answer (score 3):

As you've said, Linq to Entities doesn't recognize `.ToString()` calls; it doesn't know how to convert these into SQL.  However, you can run that in memory; simply resolve the objects (call `.ToList()` or something) and then perform the select statement on the in-memory objects.  It'll be Linq to Objects and that'll be permitted.

Whether that will work for the purpose you intend is a different question but you definitely will be able to call `.ToString()` on any object in this way.

Comment: What if i want to query just one object, not to list ?

Comment: @TariqN Even easier.  Get the one object... and call ToString on its property.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best thing you could do is retrieve the object from database as they are, by using ToList() or an equivalent method to actually do the query, then after that, you work on the retrieved list to convert to the objects you want to send to Android. As far as I know, there is no translated method to T-SQL from LinqToEntities to convert a binary field into a Base64 string.

Comment: What if i want to query just one object, not to list ? It work with list of objects, but not with one object.

Comment: Just change your Where() Linq method to FirstOrDefault(), I guess, while maintaining the conditions of your query.

Comment: I can call FirstOrDefault() method but after that i can't call Select method.

Comment: Then switch your last ToList() method to FirstOrDefault().

Comment: ProductVM p = db.Products.Where(x=>x.ProductID == id).FirstOrDefault().ClapClapThereIsNoSelectMethodHere

Comment: Ok i solved this. I should call "ToLis()" method before Select in both cases (1.when geting single object, 2.when geting list ). 
http://pastebin.com/migi300g

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this helps. As @Casey say:

> Linq to Entities doesn't recognize .ToString() calls; it doesn't know how to convert these into SQL. However, you can run that in memory; simply resolve the objects (call .ToList() or something) and then perform the select statement on the in-memory objects. It'll be Linq to Objects and that'll be permitted.

I tried it on my code and it works. What i done ? I first call *ToList()* method whenever i getting data from database, and then perform the operations.

This code works fine...

```
 List<NarudzbeVM> narudzbe = db.Narudzbe.Where(x => x.KupacID == id).ToList().
                                        Select(x => new NarudzbeVM()
                                        {
                                            BrojNarudzbe = x.BrojNarudzbe,
                                            Datum = x.Datum,
                                            KupacID = x.KupacID,
                                            NarudzbaID = x.NarudzbaID,
                                            Otkazano = x.Otkazano,
                                            Status = x.Status,
                                            StavkeNarudzbe = db.NarudzbaStavke.Where(y => y.NarudzbaID == x.NarudzbaID).ToList().
                                                             Select(z => new NarudzbaStavkeVM()
                                                             {
                                                                 Kolicina = z.Kolicina,
                                                                 NarudzbaID = z.NarudzbaID,
                                                                 NarudzbaStavkaID = z.NarudzbaStavkaID,
                                                                 ProizvodID = z.ProizvodID,
                                                                 Proizvod = db.Proizvodi.Where(k => k.ProizvodID == z.ProizvodID).ToList().
                                                                             Select(t => new ProizvodTest()
                                                                             {
                                                                                 Cijena = t.Cijena,
                                                                                 ProizvodID = t.ProizvodID,
                                                                                 JedinicaMjere = t.JediniceMjere.Naziv,
                                                                                 VrstaProizvoda = t.VrsteProizvoda.Naziv,
                                                                                 Naziv = t.Naziv,
                                                                                 Sifra = t.Sifra,
                                                                                 SlikaThumb = Convert.ToBase64String(t.SlikaThumb),
                                                                             }).FirstOrDefault()
                                                             }).ToList()

                                        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

try with this

```
string yourString= System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(
                System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(yorbyteArray));
```

Comment: The byte array is suppoed to represent an image, this will fail.

Comment: `Encoding.Default`! It is unlikely that the person who stored that data in the database knows the default encoding used by this client computer. (Just as it might not be likely that the person writing this code knows the same.)